# Pyramid aztec in C++

Tags: c++

I am new in  C++.
I am Trying to create an program which in output give  me like this

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

HEre it is my try

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int const n=10;
int main (){
 int i,j,k,mat[n][n];   

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){

            mat[i][j]=?
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And?  Did it fail to compile, give you the wrong output, kill a kitten?

Comment: He's asking what should be replace the ? in mat[i][j]=?

Comment: yes  what sould i write  '?'

Comment: @Aryan How about starting with a function that fills one given row of the matrix? Can you do this?

Comment: yea  i know using  fucntion but not so complicated

Comment: `mat[i][j] = 1 + min(min(i, n - i - 1), min(j, n - j - 1));`. The accepted answer didn't answer the actual question, so here it is. Next time please try harder before asking a question. A "try" should really be a try, not the code around the main problem.

Comment: @Dialecticus  I am sure that the assignment has to be done without using arrays. So the presented answers to the question are wrong solutions in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inefficient solution but seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int const n=10;

int main ()
{
    int i, j, mat[n][n] = { 0 };
    int indent;

    for (indent = 0; indent <= n/2; indent++) {
        for (i = indent; i < n-indent; i++) {
            for (j = indent; j < n-indent; j++) {
                mat[i][j]++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Corrected, thanks @BaummitAugen! That said it's really not optimal, I can think of at least one way to make it slightly less brute force but still brute force.

Comment: yes in odd n. something incorrect
how can be corrected ?

Comment: That isn't surprising. Given `indent <= n/2` I'd expect differing behaviors for even and odd integers given rounding. If you debug it and go through what's its doing, fixing it should be trivial.

Comment: Changing to <= (from the orignal < that I wrote) fixes it.

Comment: @Ron Kuper As for me then it is not a good solution because the assignment does not require to create an array. Moreover the initial value N (the size of the side of the square) can be changed and set by the user during run-time of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a shot just for fun too and amazingly, my answer came out very close to yours :)  Just write squares of the same number, bringing in the corners each loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int const n=5;

int main ()
{
    int i, j, k, mat[n][n];

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    {
        for (i = k; i < n-k; i++)
        {
            for (j = k; j < n-k; j++) 
            {
                mat[i][j] = k+1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        {
            cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```